# Installed php5.6 on ubuntu 16 enable extensions

Tags: php

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini

files:

- /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini

### - /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

sudo a2enmode rewrite -- something i did
Now it started 
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini

How to enable php5.6 extensions..kindly help me to resolve??

this is coming when run command "composer update" in laravel folder.